# Uniform posterior on bounded space

Tags: bayesian, posterior, dirichlet-distribution, uninformative-prior

In a particular Bayesian problem, I have encountered a choice of parameters that leads to a uniform posterior distribution. Given prior

\begin{equation}
    p(\boldsymbol{\pi}) =Dirichlet(\boldsymbol{\alpha}), \quad \text{with}\ \boldsymbol{\alpha} = [0,\dots,0].
\end{equation}

we consider a multinomial distribution whose support is $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ and $\text{Pr}(X=x_i)=\pi_i(\sum_i\pi_i=1)$

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:likelihood}
    p(X|\boldsymbol{\pi}) = \mathcal{M}ulti_{k}(n,\boldsymbol{\pi}),
\end{equation}

we find the posterior
\begin{align*}
    p(\boldsymbol{\pi}|X) &\propto p(X|\boldsymbol{\pi})p(\boldsymbol{\pi})\\
    & \propto \prod_{i}\pi_i\prod_{i}\pi_{i}^{\alpha_i-1}\\
    & \propto \prod_i\pi_i^{\alpha_i}.
\end{align*}

to be a uniform distribution

\begin{equation}
    p(\boldsymbol{\pi}|X) =Dirichlet(\boldsymbol{\alpha}), \quad \text{with}\ \boldsymbol{\alpha} = [1,\dots,1].
\end{equation}

I was wondering if it is uniform, why is this called a posterior then? How can we have a posterior distribution that is a uniform distribution?

Comment: *All* (continuous) posterior distributions are uniform when their variables are suitably expressed.  (This is known as the Probability Integral Transform.)

Comment: @whuber: However, the reparameterisation would most likely depend on the observable, which would then make it an object with no prior!

Comment: @Xi'an Perhaps.  But--especially for discrete data distributions with large-probability modes--given a prior, one could anticipate the most likely posterior and *before observing the data* choose a parameterization for which that posterior has a uniform distribution.  Indeed, that very well could be what the OP has inadvertently done ;-).

Comment: @whuber Thanks. We have the likelihood and so we know what is the distribution of the observations. What do you mean by 'before observing the data'?

Comment: Although you might have a likelihood, you do *not* know the distribution of the observations: that's the thing you're trying to discover!

Comment: @whuber I think you understand what i don't understand but I don't understand what I don't understand. I came upon this example and someone asked me the following two questions: "How can you have a posterior distribution that a) does not depend on data and b) is a uniform distribution?" I see the buzzwords "Uniform does not mean uninformative" and "before observing the data" in your comments but it seems that both question and answer are flying over my head.

Comment: You aren't reading my comments, then, because I don't use "buzzwords" and I don't use "uninformative."  The restated question in your comment is *completely* different than the question you actually posted because you failed to mention the "does not depend on data" part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE: My answer was written based on an earlier formulation of the question, namely on how having a uniform Dirichlet $\mathcal D(1,\ldots,1)$ posterior was at all possible. I proposed this setting as an illustration of a possible case. The question later got edited and, behold!, coincided with this case.**

Consider the special following case of

1. an improper prior on $\mathbf p=(p_1,\ldots,p_k)\in\mathfrak S_k$, the $k$-th dimensional simplex, proportional to$$\pi(\mathbf p)\propto \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{-1}\tag{1}$$
2. an observation $\mathbf x=(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ of $\mathbf X\sim\mathcal M_k(k;\mathbf p)$ equal to $(1,\ldots,1)$
3. a posterior equal to the Dirichlet $\mathcal D(1,\ldots,1)$ distribution

To comment on this special case,

1. the posterior obviously depends on the data. Were the data $\mathbf x=(0,\ldots,0,k)$ the posterior would be another Dirichlet distribution. Any other observation than $(1,\ldots,1)$ does not produce a Uniform posterior (with this prior (1)).
2. A Uniform posterior is a distribution and as such contains information about the probability parameter $\mathbf p$. It is limited because the data is limited but increasing the number of observations will see the posterior concentrate. There is nothing paradoxical with having a uniform prior with a single observation, at least in a sampling distribution over a finite set. Unless the likelihood is constant in the parameter, this is impossible in a continuous setting.

Comment: Yes, you read my mind! I wanted to make it clear that my question was not on give an example (maybe I didn't word it correctly at first). The discussion on the comments are closer to what I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I think second point should be modified as follows: "an observation $\mathbf x=(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ of $\mathbf X\sim\mathcal M_k(k;\mathbf p)$ with support on $\mathbf d=\left(d_{1}, \ldots, d_{K}\right)$ and $\mathbf n=(1,\ldots,1)$ where $n_k$ the number of $x_{i}$ equal to $d_{k}$". Reading yours gave me the impression that the actual observations are $(1,\ldots,1)$, while it is the number of repetitions of each possible observation $n_k$ that should be $1$.